# How do I check in to a place with Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, checkin

I'm looking to use the Facebook PHP SDK to be able to "check in" to places on Facebook from a widget on my site.

I'm having some trouble figuring this out. Do I need to go and create a Facebook Graph object of the place I want to check in to. By this I mean use the OpenGraph Markup and create a file on my website that represents the place.

I have successfully created one of these but it was a movie and not a place. I'm having trouble creating it for a place/venue. Does anybody have any samples?

Thanks.

**Update:**
I keep getting this error is anybody familiar with it? Thanks.
"(#100) Param place must be a valid page ID"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only check in to existing Pages (specifically, those with location information, AKA Places) - these are the real places on Facebook.com which were created there or via the Facebook mobile apps

You can't check into Open Graph objects even if they're defined with location information

Comment: Thank you.

Literally in the last ten minutes I was able to get this working by checking into a fan page that was also a "Place"..

This is not going to be fun as I am developing a plugin for a shopping mall website with many shops. Each shop(place) will need to  be created.. :-/

Comment: Hello Friend, Is there a way to send check in information without using place picker, by sending longitude and latitude information in facebook open graph action.

Comment: @Igy Can you post a link here for the docs for movie check - in apis? I searched it but didn't get any?

Comment: This answer was 4 years old - please check the current documentation as this answer likely isn't accurate anymore